# jquery.ui tooltip: Show tooltip only after hover for a duration of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I would like to show the tooltip over an element only if I have kept the mouse there for 1 second. If I hover for less than 1 second, the tooltip should not show. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply set the `delay` parameter which I found in the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-show)
The code could look like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selector').tooltip({
    show: { effect: 'slideDown', delay: 1000, duration: 250 }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="selector" title="Tooltip with delay and duration">TEST</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `show:{duration:value}` option while initializing the `tooltip` as below:

```
$( "#elementid" ).tooltip({
    show: { duration: 2000 }
});
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/587n9/81/)**

Comment: Is there anyway to make tooltip run content only after it has been fully shown/loaded? Because tooltip still basically loads the content while the effects are still being shown.

Comment: Well, you have `tooltipopen` event to do tasks once `tooltip` is opened. **[Here's one example](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/587n9/88/)**. But initially the title attribute should have some dummy value, atleast **space**, to initialize tooltip.. Check the demo and let me know..